# yii2 bootstrap align text with checkbox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2, yii2-basic-app

how I align the text horizontally with check box in yii 2 bootstrap, something like the imagem in the attachment.

[image]

Comment: Please can you put the image in the question rather than linking to a temporary image? In a year's time, when your imagur image is deleted, this question will be meaningless!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'status')->checkbox([1 => 'Active'])->label('Status'); ?>
```

It will by default come horizantally only.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using an Active Field you can use the label function to the checkbox field, this will align by default your label Horizontally next to the checkbox.

```
public $this checkbox ( $options = [], $enclosedByLabel = true )
```

Check the [yii2 official documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#checkbox%28%29-detail) for more options